# Angularjs typeahead not displaying the options on 2nd input focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a dropdown control and a txt input control which is bound to typeahead control.
Initially when I'll display category

[image]

As soon as I get to the input box for filtering and the control gets the focus I'm able to get the results:

[image]

As a next step I'll change the filter value to Priority

[image]

But when I click the input textbox nothing happens until I'll enter some value and clear it, please check the gif at this url https://i.gyazo.com/d95937ade5b9c05ec3adf169c7533d50.mp4

The input textbox has this markup :

```
<input name="states" ng-trim="false" id="states" type="text" placeholder="Start Filtering..." ng-model="selected" typeahead-editable="false" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-min-length="0">
```

Comment: To help you out I would more information, can you add some more code. But for the instance can you try to add $scope.$apply() in the ngchange callback of filter

Comment: I don't find any issue in the code which you have provided. The state data is getting undefined after changing the filter value. Check once if you are getting $scope.states value after changing the filter or not.
Put the debugger or try to print in html itself by {{state}}.

Comment: it would be way easier to answer if you could provide a code snippet , like in https://stackblitz.com, but for now set a watch to the model and see in console what happens to it when you are using your inputs